# Updating from 12.04 to 14.04 - Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, gtk, pygtk

I'm attempting to upgrade my work machine from 12.04 to 14.04, but having issues.

`sudo update-manager -d`:

```
** (update-manager:20416): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=f01c8e2b23ace751460ef7f800000009 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 26, in <module>
from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 76, in load_module
dynamic_module._load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 224, in _load
overrides_modules = __import__('gi.overrides', fromlist=[self._namespace])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1533, in <module>
raise RuntimeError("Gtk couldn't be initialized")
RuntimeError: Gtk couldn't be initialized
```

I've tried stuff like removing `.Xauthority`

Launching it without sudo works, but it fails when I click upgrade:

```
authenticate 'trusty.tar.gz' against 'trusty.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'trusty.tar.gz'
can't load DistUpgradeViewGtk3 (Gtk couldn't be initialized)
```

Any ideas on how I can launch `sudo update-manager -d` ?

Comment: Is this from a graphical terminal or are you doing this via a TTY or over SSH?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY update-manager -d
```

Comment: `sudo` shouldn’t munch the variables (so they shouldn’t need persisting manually, see: `sudo bash -c 'echo $DISPLAY'`) and you shouldn't run graphical things with plain-old sudo (for the very reason that they can ruin your .Xauthority, etc).